# MySQL convert timestamp to timezone for search query

Tags: mysql, laravel, datetime, timezone, php-carbon

I have a MySQL database with a table called `orders` and a `timestamp` column called `created_at`

All timestamps are stored in UTC format and converted back to the users local time on the front end - currently this is set to 'Europe/London'

In London we have DST between April and November where the clocks are GMT+1 e.g an order created at `27-10-2019 00:00` localtime would be saved as `26-10-2019 23:00` UTC

A user can search for all orders created between certain dates. In MySQL I can use the following function to convert the dates back to local timezone to achieve this e.g:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM orders 
 WHERE DATE(CONVERT_TZ(created_at, 'UTC','Europe/London')) >= '27-10-2019' 
   AND DATE(CONVERT_TZ(created_at, 'UTC','Europe/London')) <= '27-10-2019'
```

However I am on a shared hosting and the MySQL timezone tables are not loaded so unable to use named timezone. I only need to use the one timezone and you probably thinking then why not just store all timestamps as `Europe/London` instead of `UTC`. I want to keep it as 'UTC' to accommodate other timezones in the future.

Is there a workaround to return the correct results without using named timezone?

Note the query is actually written using laravels eloqeunt query builder in php as follows:

```
if (isset($queryString['from_date'])) {
    $query = $query->whereRaw('DATE(orders.created_at) >= ?', [Carbon::parse($queryString['from_date'])->format('Y-m-d')]);
}

if (isset($queryString['to_date'])) {
    $query = $query->whereRaw('DATE(orders.created_at) <= ?', [Carbon::parse($queryString['to_date'])->format('Y-m-d')]);
}
```

At first I thought a solution would be to convert the user entered dates to UTC as well however when I have orders created on the following dates, the results miss out the second record:

```
created_at
-------------------------------------------------------------
27-10-2019 00:00 (localtime) - saved as 26-10-2019 23:00 (UTC)
27-10-2019 01:00 (localtime) - saved as 27-10-2019 00:00 (UTC)
```

Any help appreciated.

*** UPDATE ***

By incrementing the end date (and the resulting datetime checked with `<` instead of `<=` does not work when DST is not in effect. In the UK DST was switched off this year on the 2019-10-27. Lets say you have orders created on the following dates:

```
created_at (Europe/London)                   created_at (UTC) as saved in DB
------------------------------------         --------------------------------
2019-10-26 23:00                             2019-10-26 22:00  (UTC)
2019-10-27 03:00                             2019-10-27 03:00  (UTC)
```

User want to list all orders created on the `2019-10-27`. Using `2019-10-27` as the user selected date, the start date becomes `2019-10-26` using php Carbon:

```
Carbon\Carbon::parse('27 Oct 2019', 'Europe/London')->timezone('UTC')->format('Y-m-d')
=> "2019-10-26"
```

and end date becomes `2019-10-28`

```
Carbon\Carbon::parse('27 Oct 2019', 'Europe/London')->addDay()->timezone('UTC')->format('Y-m-d')
=> "2019-10-28"
```

Which means the query ends up as:

```
WHERE created_at >= "2019-10-26"
  AND created_at < "2019-10-28"
```

So in the above scenario you end up with a result set that will include orders created on the `2019-10-26` which was not the desired results.

Comment: First thing, don't do searches using MySQL DATE() function because in this situation you will not use the eventual index you have on created_at (you do have indexes, right?).
Second thing: it's easier do to searches for the end interval using the "<" operator, with the "next day" as the parameter.

Combining these two... convert "2019-10-27 00:00:00" and "2019-10-28 00:00:00" to UTC and apply those to the search. You'll then have the condition: created_at >= '2019-10-26 23:00:00' AND created_at < '2019-10-28 20:00:00', which should cover your case (and all others).

Comment: @AndreiKovacs `it's easier do to searches for the end interval using the "<" operator, with the "next day" as the parameter` will only work when DST is on. It will not work for records created when DST is off?

Comment: The data in MySQL is in UTC. No DST there. And the conversion on the "local" part adds or removes that DST... that's why the start interval had 23:00:00 but the end interval was not changed. If you do a timezone conversion of "2019-10-28 00:00:00" to UTC using DateTime you get "2019-10-28 00:00:00".

Comment: for it to funtion, you have to compare with a datetime, not with a date. So, add H:i:s also to the format. `Carbon\Carbon::parse('27 Oct 2019 00:00:00', 'Europe/London')->timezone('UTC')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') ---> 2019-10-26 23:00:00
. Carbon\Carbon::parse('28 Oct 2019 00:00:00', 'Europe/London')->timezone('UTC')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') ---> 2019-10-28 00:00:00.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should complain to your hosting provider.  If the timezones tables are not installed and kept up to date, it is in effect a broken installation of MySQL.

But even if they were there, you should convert the requested date range to utc in your query, not the other way around:

```
WHERE created_at >= CONVERT_TZ('2019-10-27', 'Europe/London', 'UTC')
AND created_at < CONVERT_TZ(DATE_ADD('2019-10-27', INTERVAL 1 DAY), 'Europe/London', 'UTC')
```

This is more efficient, as well as allowing an index on created_at to be used.

Without the timezones tables, you can perform the conversion on the start and end dates in php that duplicates the SQL above.

Note that you are converting to a datetime, not a date, and your end date needs to be incremented (and the resulting datetime checked with `<` not `<=`) to properly include the full day; I suspect this may have been the source of your problem when trying to convert to utc in your code.

Comment: the above `end date needs to be incremented (and the resulting datetime checked with < not <=) ` will work only when DST is on. In months where orders are created when DST is off it will not work?

Comment: No, it will work just fine.  The user provides and end date (e.g. 2019-07-01 or 2019-12-01).  You increment it, and then convert it from Europe/London to utc, producing e.g. 2019-07-01 23:00:00 and 2019-12-02 00:00:00, respectively.  Then use that in your query to test `created_at < ?`.  Does that make sense?

Comment: please see my updated post as to why this doesn't work

Comment: You need to convert the BST date to a UTC datetime,  not just a date.  Reread my answer and previous comment

Comment: ah yes my bad...you are right I needed to remove `format('Y-m-d')`. It's is working now. Many thanks.

Comment: @ysth Your answer helped me a lot. I was stuck with UTC to local time zone. Hats off to you man!! Thank you so much!